# Is .htaccess and web.config directory access blocking relyable?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

### I need to completely block the access of some directories of my PHP application.

This is how my application file system looks like:

```
www
├── core
│   ├── .htaccess
│   └── many .php files
│
├── logs
│   ├── .htaccess
│   └── many .log files
│
├── .htaccess
├── index.php
└── web.config
```

---

both www/core/.htaccess and www/logs/.htaccess look exactly the same:

```
deny from all
```

---

www/.htaccess is as described:

```
#   Friendly-url definitions
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

---

Also, my web.config for IIS servers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <add segment="core"/>
                    <add segment="settings"/>
                    <add segment="logs"/>
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

### Is this enough?

I used to put in all my PHP include files a "index.php existence" verification before any other code to make sure it wouldn't be directly accessed. If the file were directly accessed, it'd return 404. But I want to get rid of those annoying verification lines.

Now, with all those .htaccess files, when I try to directly access a file in one of those folders my request is completely "ignored" and `www/index.php` is executed - much better than a 404-error.

But, is this enough? Can I fearless rely on .htaccess and remove all those index-verification repetitiveness? What about web.config for IIS?

**PS: As the application is being made to run in all server configurations possible, I cannot guarantee the possibility of putting those directories outside `www`. Also, it is *required* to work in both Apache and IIS servers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether "enough" is good enough for you. For the most part, the `deny from all` is good enough.

Depending on the server setup, or your scripts, a possible to exploit in one of those things that could cause the htaccess file from being overwritten. So in apache, you can setup the rules in your server/vhost config instead of htaccess files.

The best way is probably still moving the sensitive files out of your document root.

Comment: So, the exploit is the possibility of one script overwrite one `.htaccess`? If so, that would only happen if it were completely intentional by the programmer, right?

Comment: I agree the best to do is moving out of document root.

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira well, for example, wordpress sites had plugins that's broken and allowed an unintentional overwrite of a php file, allowing an attacker to upload a php file that will overwrite other files, like htaccess files. I don't know what your app looks like, or how well tested and vetted it is, but it's always a possibility.

Comment: Thank you. Happily, I am not responsible for this kind of situation.